# Two connections in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, connection, adsl

I have one wire that goes to my laptop. I can connect local network and ADSL internet in Windows *simultaneously*. I created the ADSL-connection in Ubuntu and it works well (I can browse Internet). But I can't connect to local network (i.e. to IPs 192.168.xxx.yyy).

Comment: "A wire that goes to your laptop" Presumably an ethernet cable that has a router on the other end? Also, what version of Ubuntu are you using? And most importantly read this: http://bit.ly/117GoQ

Comment: @trideceth12 I've edited question.

Comment: Are you dual booting? Are you virtualizing?

Comment: @Josh , If you mean my linux installation, then it is dual boot. Linux has its own partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in standard network-manager. It somehow (in a very strange way) overwrites routes for `eth0` (LAN), making LAN inaccessible.

Solution for my problem – manually add the following to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168....
netmask 255.255....
gateway 192.168....
```

And connect to DSL using `pppoeconf`, `pon` and `poff` commands.